# How can I add validation message to observablearray?

Tags: html, validation, knockout.js

Based on this tutorial: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/gridEditor.html
We have inputs with validation rules in css classes:

```
<td><input class='required' data-bind='value: name, uniqueName: true' /></td>
<td><input class='required number' data-bind='value: price, uniqueName: true' /></td>
```

How can I set my own error message, for example 'Value in this field is required and must be a number.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the title of the input to message you want to give.

```
<td><input class='required' title='my custom error message' data-bind='value: name, uniqueName: true' /></td>
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7RDc3/4248/) you follow. I modified it to have custom error message

By the way, this is an issue about HTML validation; it has nothing to do with knockout.